# Trying to drag and drop onto an SVG canvas with accurate coordinates

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement drag and drop an image element onto an SVG canvas but the elements are not in the same div.  I have tried to use clientX and clientY properties but they are out by about 20 pixels when I come to drop the element.  I think the problem is that the SVG coordinates work from the top of the root SVG element  but drag and drop coordinates are from the visible view port.  When I try to release the rock image on the canvas it just seems to go to any random place on it and sometimes off the canvas completely.

[image: Screenshot of my attempt]

I have uploaded all my code to https://github.com/kiwiheretic/gravity

(It shouldn't be too difficult to just clone the repo and open index.html within the browser to see the problem.)

The relevant HTML code is as follows:

```
      <div style="background-color:black; width: min-content;">
        <svg id="space" width="600" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div id="object-block-1" class="objects">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="asteroid.png" alt="asteroid">
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
```

The relevant javascript code is:

```
     var objblock = document.getElementById("object-block-1");
     objblock.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
       draggedObject = evt.target;
     
     });
     objbl
     objblock.addEventListener("dragend", function(evt) {
        var x = evt.clientX;
        var y = evt.clientY;
        var src = draggedObject.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log([x,y]);
        var space = document.getElementById("space");
        var tgt = space.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (doesPointCollide(x,y,tgt)) {
          //asteroid = makeAsteroid(x, y, 50, 50);
          //space.appendChild(asteroid);
        }
     });
     objblock.addEventListener("drag", function(evt) {
        var space = document.getElementById("space");
        var rect = space.getBoundingClientRect();
        var src = draggedObject.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = (src.x - rect.x) + evt.clientX;
        var y = (src.y + rect.y) + evt.clientY;
        document.getElementsByName("drag-x")[0].value = parseInt(x);
        document.getElementsByName("drag-y")[0].value = parseInt(y);
     
     });
```

I am using the right hand input boxes as kind of a debugging aid.  I am not sure why drag-x and drag-y are not resolving to suitable SVG coordinates within the canvas and what needs to be done to fix that.

Any idea what javascript mouse event attributes and element attributes to work out my SVG coordinates for drag and drop?

Comment: You will have a greater chance of help if you paste the relevant code into your post.

Comment: Relevant code posted as far as I can tell.  It's always possible that the real issue may lie somewhere else.